# Get rid of the following error with Docker: Handler for GET /v1.38/nodes returned error: This node is not a swarm manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am not using Docker Swarm and everytime I run `docker inspect some_container` I get the following error in syslog:

```
dockerd[2019]: time="..." level=error \
    msg="Handler for GET /v1.38/secrets returned error: \
    This node is not a swarm manager. \
    Use \"docker swarm init\" or \"docker swarm join\" to \
    connect this node to swarm and try again."
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: which docker version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `docker-ce 18.06`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect a container from Docker 1.13 is added inspect "per object type".

From the [docker container inspect doc](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/container_inspect/):

```
docker container inspect some_container
```

This is a known bug, please take a look into [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/29246)

Is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26783):

> @mfilotto this should be fixed by #29246, which is part of docker
>   1.13.1. The errors are safe to ignore though.
>
> As a workaround, you can use docker inspect --type=container foo if
>   you want to inspect a container, etc. Docker 1.13 adds inspect "per
>   object type", e.g. docker image inspect foo, docker container inspect
>   foo, etc
>
> I'll close this issue, because this should be fixed, but feel free to
>   comment after I closed